# meteor 1.4 - (node) sys is deprecated. Use util instead

Tags: node.js, meteor

Personally, I have a problem when running meteor ...

The app work perfectly but console show me exception

**(node) sys is deprecated. Use util instead.**

I have no idea of what might be ... need help ....

[image]

Comment: Added image into the question. It would be better to include its text instead of an image of a text.

Answer (score 2):

Probably one or more of your packages is using `require('sys')` (which has been deprecated in [Node 4.0.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.0.0/CHANGELOG.md#notable-changes)), in this case you have to check which one are using it and update them.

If you find that you are using it in your own code, replace `require('sys')` with `require('util')`

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.

Code or modules used sys.
I find my project code includ "node_modules" as "sys." keyword.

I found it in "officegen" npm module.
remove this module, error message go away.

Answer (score 0):

One can fix this warning in their personal project. It's a manual process for fixing this issue in an individual project. Go to your node modules folder and find the logger folder inside it. Inside the logger folder, you will find a logger.js file. Open the logger.js file and do as the following code suggests:-

```
var sys=require('sys'); // import 'sys' to 'util'
var sys=require('util');
```

means replace the code on LHS via code on RHS